# Removing text between two specific strings

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have a file as below:

```
mime PI Name: ISHO SUCCESS RATE RT, Value: 95.663826
scr  PI Name: RRC Access Failures due to UU, Value: 0.13394141
prog PI Name: RRC Access Failures due to UU, Value: 0.16077702
sch PI Name: RRC Access Failures due to UU, Value: 0.11781933
```

I want to remove text `PI` till `Value:`. I tried

```
sed '/<PI>/,/<\/Value:>/d'
```

Any help?

Answer (score 29):

Replace everything from `PI` to `Value:` with empty string:

```
sed 's/PI.*Value://'
```

Comment: Will this work if `PI` and `Value:` occur on different lines?

Comment: ^ no, this will not work on multiple lines. See below for that solution.

Answer (score 6):

Using the `d` command in `sed` will delete the whole line. Also, I'm not sure why you're using `<` and `>`. Perhaps you're confusing them with `\<` and `\>` that `grep` uses to denote word boundaries? In that case, you should know that `sed` uses `\b` for both types of word boundaries (beginning and ending). So you can write something like this:

```
sed -i 's/\bPI\b.*\bValue:\b//' your_file
```

For extra robustness, I would use `perl` for lazy quantification of `.` so that you only delete the text between the first occurrence of `PI` and the first occurrence of `Value:`. Of course it all depends on your use case.

```
perl -pi -e 's{ \b PI \b .*? \b Value: \b}{}x' your_file
```

Answer (score 6):

Use this below code to remove multiple lines between patterns (including lines with patterns):

```
sed "/PI/,/Value:/d" your_file
```

If you want to modify your_file directly:

```
sed -i "/PI/,/Value:/d" your_file
```

Comment: Notice the distinction here -- this deletes *lines* in a range, while the question is asking for deleting *text* between two strings.